# How do I establish the network sharing to my WinXP server network drive from my Mac notebook?

Tags: macos, file-sharing, windows-server

I have been able to connect to my WinXP server's shared drives by using Finder's <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> to browse the network.  Unfortunately, when the server gets rebooted, the connection drops and sometimes I cannot get reconnected.

I have specified different protocols (afp / cifs / smb) and different login names (connect as...) with limited success.  Once I find the right combination, I am good for a few weeks.

Once, it seems as though I had to unshared and shared the drive to get it to work.  Unfortunately, it is very frustrating, so I try multiple things at one time, so when I finally get to the success point -- I honestly don't know what worked.

I followed Mac help, surfed for instructions, issues, etc., but nothing appears to be consistent.  I would love for this thread to be the ultimate answer for all time!

Can anyone help me?  If my description or question need more detail, please ask away!

Comment: Does your XP server always come back up with the same IP address? Have you tried connecting directly by IP using SMB? (ex: smb://192.168.0.5)

Comment: When you are unable to connect what errors are you getting? -36, -50?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... there is often a client- and a server-side answer to such problems.  I ran into to this problem again and I 'ejected' my USB drive, disconnected the cable and then plugged it back in.  But the problem persisted.  I even dropped and added the sharing permissions (that appeared to solve the problem the first time I experienced this -- may have been a coincidence and is not typically an option for the client-user).

This morning I decided to shutdown my Mac and when it came up, I went to Finder to look for the network drive and I got the login prompt.  Now I am connected.

I tend to leave my Mac sleeping 7x24 when I am not using it so it is always 'hot' and ready to work.  But I think that accumulates hidden problems and it deserves a good 'boot' every once in a while.

Problem solved (again) and in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware problem!  For some reason the USB drive is going silent.  I was rebooting the server for other reasons and clearing up (masking) the problem.  My connection is now staying up across Mac reboots, sleep/resume, etc.

Thanks for the help, suggestions, etc.

Sorry for the misdiagnosed problem.

BTW - Yes, I did try SMB as suggest by Darren, what I didn't do was look at the access light on the USB drive :((

Also, the error was that Finder, using the browse feature, would simply timeout and say 'not found.'